# What Farscape Episodes Are Important to the Arc?

Tags: suggested-order, farscape

My girlfriend and I just started watching *Farscape* on Netflix.  I had started watching it before, but forgot a lot.  I remember little bits and pieces, like the girl with blue skin and white hair showing up for the first time, some guy in latex (Scorpius, I think?), one or two scenes of D'Argo being whacked so he'd bleed clear, and that Kent McCord shows up for at least a 2nd guest shot.

And that's about it.  And that's all I want to know about it so I can watch it with her and we can enjoy seeing it develop.  So do NOT include spoilers here, don't include episodes summaries, and don't drop plot points for the story arc.

We got to the 2nd episode last night and she saw the description that included some kind of big bugs in it and didn't want to watch it.  (This was after recently seeing one of the bug episodes in *Primeval*.)  I told her that I didn't know how intricate *Farcsape* was, but that it had an overall story arc, and we might miss something.  She still wanted to skip it.

So that leads to a few questions.  I don't know how intricate or in depth any story arc is, but I'd like to know which episodes are important to the long term story arc.  If it's shorter to list episodes needed for the arc (that we should make sure we watch), that's fine.  If it's shorter to list the episodes NOT in the arc, that's okay, too.

I just want to be sure that we don't skip episodes that are important to any story arcs while watching *Farscape*.

Comment: Even the ones that aren't directly connected to the main story arc contain important information. And those bugs are not as bad by any means.

Comment: I would recommend editing this down to remove somewhat extraneous question backstory from the first 2-3 paragraphs

Comment: @ewanm89: By "not as bad," do you mean not as bad as the ones in _Primeval_?

Comment: I just don't understand people who want to skip along arc episodes and miss the "non-arc" - there are very few in many series that don't contribute to character development - especially something like Farscape. Of course, if there are phobia reasons to skip, that's a little different, and you're better off *not* watching something that is going to make you uncomfortable or unhappy.

Comment: Farscape is a complex show with very complicated relationships between all of the characters both protagonists and antagonists. If you skip an episode, any episode, you are likely to miss something you will have wanted to see or know in the future. Farscape is a beautiful show because of the harmonies both overt and subtle between its players. Those relationships change over the course of the show and often in ways not expected. My advice is to NOT SKIP anything and enjoy the ride the way its delivered. It's worth the trip. Farscape is one of the finest space opera's ever crafted. Enjoy!

Comment: Every last episode.  Every one.  All of them.

Comment: I have to agree with the last 3 comments as well.  Farscape is designed around character development, and any skipping will cause you to miss out.  Even the one-off "filler" episodes (such as the first one with Maldis) can completely change the nature of a character.

Comment: As you haven't yet found your answer, how about you watch the bug episode alone, and fill in your girlfriend on what she's missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't skip any.

Farscape is designed around character development and the changing relationship between the cast.  Most especially in the early episodes, when the characters had never met each other before then, and Crichton is struggling to understand the new "rules" of that section of the galaxy.

For example,

> 1x08, [That Old Black Magic](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/That_Old_Black_Magic), can easily be considered such a filler episode, but it's also the one where the peace-loving Zhaan opens up to her murderous, destructive side, which becomes a *major* point later on.  It also escalates Crais's pursuit of Crichton, as well as giving us backstory on *why* the Peacekeepers are as they are.
>
> 1x09, [DNA Mad Scientist](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/DNA_Mad_Scientist) is another example.  The obvious one is showing everyone's desperation with getting home, but it's also a precursor to Aeryn's relationship with Pilot.

Answer (score 6):

I too am watching Farscape with my boyfriend :D We're at the second season finale right now...
You should watch the first 2 or 3 episodes to get a feel of the overall alien atmosphere (compared to what other shows are offering), and you should DEFINITELY watch anything that comes in 2 or 3 parts. Those are really really important.

Have a look here, on Wikipedia to see which span on more than one part

EDIT: You should frelling watch all of them actually

Answer (score -1):

Farscape is not like other shows. If you feel comfortable skipping - perhaps it is better not to watch it at all, and return to the show … later. Each episode has its purpose! Missing even a single episode can break the magic.

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning of Farscape: The Peacekeeper Wars narration by Ben Browder states: "Previously on Farscape." Watch that clip, then watch the full episode of each scene shown in that clip and you'll be fine.

Comment: For those not in the know, [The "Previously on Farscape" mentioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGMCS0MiRCQ) contains a scene from every episode (except possibly one or two; I think I heard about a rights issue way back when).

Comment: The only problem with this that it means the clip alone will contain a lot of spoilers.

Answer (score -6):

All you need to watch is these Farscape‬ eps S1:1,4,7,9-11,13,15,16,18-20,22. S2:1,4,5,11-13,15,16,18-22. S3:1-4,6-8,10,11,13-21. S4:1-3,5,7,8,11-13,15-22.

skip the rest.

Comment: Watch the rest!

Comment: This list needs better formatting, and some reasoning backing up your selection of episodes.